# Encountered 'MemoryError' while splitting a Pandas DataFrame column with .str.split(). How can I optimize memory usage for this operation

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, data-science, parquet

i am beginner with the parquet format file. i had got a timestamp (2018-08-14T15:30:00-0400) which i need to change in date and time i tried using pandas but the dataset is having 127946340 entries for which the program shows Memory error.

```
df1[['Date', 'Time']] = df1['timestamp'].str.split('T', 1, expand=True)
```

the error

```
    MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
      3 # Split the datetime column into date and time columns
      4 df1[['Date', 'Time']] = df1['timestamp'].str.split('T', 1, expand=True)
```

first i extracted the column and then i tried to split that column which shows the above error.

Comment: Why do you want this?  It's rarely useful to have date and time as separate entries.  When you convert that to a string, you get 24 characters, which means 5 gigabytes just for that column.  A datetime type is only 8 bytes.  It's not like you are ever going to LOOK at 128 million rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to get date and time as separate columns.

You can do this using `to_datetime` function:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp']).dt.date
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp']).dt.time
```

It'll give you the following output:

```
    timestamp   Date    Time
0   2018-08-14T15:30:00-0400    2018-08-14  15:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I'm new to the parquet format.

Vectorization and df.column.apply method below were resulting in memory error.

```
df_weather_temp[["year", "month", "date"]] = 
df_weather_temp.date.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split("-")))
df_weather_temp[['date', 'ns']] = 
df_weather_temp.date.str.split(expand=True)
df_weather_temp
```

This method works for the dataframe with 27 million rows.

```
df_weather_temp['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df_weather_temp['date']).dt.year
df_weather_temp["month"] = pd.to_datetime(df_weather_temp['date']).dt.month
df_weather_temp["new_date"] = 
pd.to_datetime(df_weather_temp['new_date']).dt.day
df_weather_temp = df_weather_temp.drop(columns=['date'])
df_weather_temp
```